# Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException when trying to get a text file

Tags: java

All I have written down is

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("TrialInput.txt");
```

I just followed information I read online. For some reason it says that

```
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
```

The file exists on my computer. So I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using FileReader causes a compiler error "unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488339/using-filereader-causes-a-compiler-error-unhandled-exception-type-filenotfounde)

Comment: There is not a full path (the most likely error), and sometimes Windows hides the extension, people actually using a file `TrialInput.txt.txt`.

Comment: Try a `System.out.println(new File("TrialInput.txt").getAbsolutePath());` to see what file you are really trying to open.